# How to access the contents of a JSON file without a key?

Tags: json, node.js, express

Basically, I am setting up a web server via Node.js and Express (I am a beginner at this) to retrieve data by reading a JSON file.
For example, this is my data.json file:

```
[{
        "color": "black",
        "category": "hue",
        "type": "primary"
    },
    {
        "color": "red",
        "category": "hue",
        "type": "primary"
    }
]
```

I am trying to retrieve all of the colors by implementing this code for it to display on localhost:

```
router.get('/colors', function (req, res) {
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/data.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        res.json(data); //this displays all of the contents of data.json
    })
});

router.get('/colors:name', function (req, res) {
    fs.readFile(__dirname + '/data.json', 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            res.json(data[i][1]); //trying to display the values of color
        }
    })
});
```

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Looks like you need a good old fashion `for` loop....or maybe even `.forEach()`.

Comment: and inside the loop, it should like something like this `data[i].color`

Comment: Unless, of course, you want to loop through the keys without knowing them, then you'd want to use `for(var key in data[i]) { var value = data[i][key]; }`

Comment: So simple thing. Just use `const newColors = data.map((item)=>item.color);`

Comment: Small point, you can `require()` json files rather than reading and parsing explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is actually pretty simple once you break it into smaller problems. Here is one way to break it down:

1. Load your JSON data into memory for use by your API.
2. Define an API route which extracts only the colours from your JSON data and sends them to the client as a JSON.

---

```
var data = [];
try {
    data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('/path/to/json'));
} catch (e) {
    // Handle JSON parse error or file not exists error etc
    data = [{
            "color": "black",
            "category": "hue",
            "type": "primary"
        },
        {
            "color": "red",
            "category": "hue",
            "type": "primary"
        }
    ]
}

router.get('/colors', function (req, res, next) {
    var colors = data.map(function (item) {
        return item.color
    }); // This will look look like: ["black","red"]
    res.json(colors); // Send your array as a JSON array to the client calling this API
})
```

Some improvements in this method:

1. The file is read only once synchronously when the application is started and the data is cached in memory for future use.
2. Using `Array.prototype.map` [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to extract an array of colors from the object.

---

Note:

You can structure the array of colors however you like and send it down as a JSON in that structure.

Examples:

```
var colors = data.map(function(item){return {color:item.color};}); // [{"color":"black"},{"color":"red"}]

var colors = {colors: data.map(function(item){return item.color;})} // { "colors" : ["black" ,"red"] }
```

---

Some gotchas in your code:

1. You are using `res.json` in a for loop which is incorrect as the response should only be sent once. Ideally, you would build the JS object in the structure you need by iterating over your data and send the completed object once with `res.json` (which I'm guessing internally `JSON.stringify`s the object and sends it as a response after setting the correct headers)
2. Reading files is an expensive operation. If you can afford to read it once and cache that data in memory, it would be efficient (Provided your data is not prohibitively large - in which case using files to store info might be inefficient to begin with)

Answer (score 1):

in express, you can do in this way

```
router.get('/colors/:name', (req, res) => {
  const key = req.params.name
  const content = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/data.json', 'utf8')
  const data = JSON.parse(content)
  const values = data.reduce((values, value) => {
    values.push(value[key])
    return values      
  }, [])
  // values => ['black', 'red']
  res.send(values)
});
```

and then `curl http://localhost/colors/color`,
you can get ['black', 'red']

Comment: Thank you so much! It helped me with my problem. Can you explain why did you use readFileSync vs readFile? And what does reduce do? I'm a beginner so any kind of resources would help immensely.

Comment: you don't need `reduce` for this. `readFileSync` blocks everything util it's completed. You don't want to use that in production. Author might have used it here for simplicity. See my comment on using `.map()`

Comment: @NidhinDavid  hahaha ,  yep,  map is very OK. but please vote me up, wo just need  2 point to 50, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking to do is:

```
res.json(data[i]['color']);
```

Comment: Thank you. It works but it only displays the first element of the JSON array. I would like to iterate through it to display all names.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't really want to use the keys in the json you may want to use the `Object.values` function.

```
...
data = JSON.parse(data)
var values = []
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    values.push(Object.values(data[i])[0]) // 0 - color, 1 - category, 2 - type
}
res.json(values) // ["black","red"]
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should never use `fs.readFileSync` in production. Any sync function will block the event loop until the execution is complete hence delaying everything afterwords *(use with caution if deemed necessary)*. A few days back I had the worst experience myself and learnt that in a hard way.

In express you can define a route with `param` or `query` and use that to `map` the contents inside `fs.readFile` callback function.

```
/** 
* get color by name
* 
* @param {String} name name of the color
* @return {Array} array of the color data matching param
*/

router.get('/colors/:name', (req, res) => {
    const color = req.params.name

    const filename = __dirname + '/data.json';

    fs.readFile('/etc/passwd', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
        if(err){
            return res.send([]); // handle any error returned by readFile function here
        }

        try{
            data = JSON.parse(data); // parse the JSON string to array

            let filtered = []; // initialise empty array

            if(data.length > 0){ // we got an ARRAY of objects, right? make your check here for the array or else any map, filter, reduce, forEach function will break the app
                filtered = data.filter((obj) => {
                    return obj.color === color; // return the object if the condition is true
                });
            }

            return res.send(filtered); // send the response 

    }
    catch(e){
      return res.send([]); // handle any error returned from JSON.parse function here
    }
  });

});
```

To summarise, use `fs.readFile` asynchronous function so that the event loop is not clogged up. Inside the callback parse through the content and then `return` the response. `return` is really important or else you might end up getting **Error: Can't set headers after they are sent**

**DISCLAIMER** This code above is untested but should work. This is just to demonstrate the idea.

Comment: Hello. Great answer. However, I disagree with a few points that you make: 1) It is not correct to generalise to say using the sync versions are always bad. It really depends on how you use them and they exist for a reason :) 2) returning the res call is not mandatory and does not necessarily preclude the error you mentioned. That is caused when the res is sent multiple times

Comment: I completely agree with you @ChiragRavindra I might have been overwhelmed while saying not using sync functions. I should've said 'use with caution'. And as of returning res its just a precaution where accidentally user might call res in the following code which might get executed. So it wouldn't harm to return if this can avoid such multiple response sent scenarios, don't you think?

Comment: Yup. Returning will help prevent subsequent calls (especially if your middleware uses a conditional which uses sends a response and there is code which also sends some other response following that).I felt that it was important to highlight that `returning the value of the res.send` call was not what necessarily precluded that error. (One case where this may happen if `next` is called before `res.send` which in turn invokes another middleware which also calls `res.send`). Again, I don't mean to nitpick.. Just thought I should highlight those points :)

Comment: That was really nice of you. Different opinions are really important as they primarily results from different experiences. Hope someday our argument might help someone even me. Really appreciated :)

Answer (score -1):

I think you can’t access JSON without key. You can use Foreach loop for(var name : object){} check about foreach it may help you

Comment: That's not true as I've seen this been done several times. However, my problem is that the JSON file given to me is an array without a key.

Comment: Use foreach loop 2 times. Foreach will work on both array and json for(var x : array){ for(var y: JSON) { x[y] // gives u individual element }}